# What is the biggest size / number of documents of index - java lucene 3.0.2 on 32 bit OS

Tags: java, winapi, lucene

I am playing around with lucene and 40GB of data (~500M of tuples, 2 fields behaving like key - value). I have created -- a suprise -- a 35 GB index which does not work. Therefore I want to create a set of smaller indicies but, for that, I need information about maximum size.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "index does not work"?

Comment: "Does not work":
* I get no results when I search in the index.
* I can not retrieve the first document in the index. 
* Luke (http://www.getopt.org/luke/) can not open my index and print out out an error message: out of index exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What filesystem do you use? Are you absolutely sure that you have created a valid index? How exactly are you indexing your data?

Theoretically you shouldn't be at the maximum by a long shot.

> **Limitations**
>
> When referring to term numbers, Lucene's current implementation uses a Java int, which means the maximum number of unique terms in any single index segment is 2,147,483,648. This is technically not a limitation of the index file format, just of Lucene's current implementation.
>
> Similarly, Lucene uses a Java int to refer to document numbers, and the index file format uses an Int32 on-disk to store document numbers. This is a limitation of both the index file format and the current implementation. Eventually these should be replaced with either UInt64 values, or better yet, VInt values which have no limit.

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/fileformats.html#Limitations

Comment: I am using the index as a map (key, value). The keys are indexed and normalized. The values are stored. 

My platform is Windows XP on NTFS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [MMapDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/MMapDirectory.html) and a 32-bit VM? If so, the address space is not enough to cover the whole index and that might have caused the problem. In that case you need to use [SimpleFSDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/SimpleFSDirectory.html) or [NIOFSDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/NIOFSDirectory.html) instead. Note that functions like [FSDirectory.open(File)](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html#open%28java.io.File%29) return a [FSDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/FSDirectory.html), which might or might not be a MMapDirectory.