# Java Exception while using Lucene

Tags: java, lucene, eclipse-3.6

Hi I tried a program using Lucene Plugin. I have multiple indexes, for searching multiple indexes I used "ParallelMultiSearcher". But while searching I m again and again getting the exception **"Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit"**. I m using eclipse Helio IDE, UBUNTU 10.04 Operating system(32 bit). 3GB ram. Lucene 3.0.3 version. 10 index files, each contains 100 records(csv files, with 10 fields). VM Arguments settings **-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m**. But I tried to increase, some times I m getting **Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap**. Even I reduced the file size and tried, and instead 10 files, i reduced to 1 file, again and again, I m getting the same error. Please, suggest solution for the above. Thank you in advance....

Comment: Could you paste your code? Because your data is too small to cause such an exception. I got the same exception but working with 40GB index (decomposed into 10 indices). You probable have a bug in your code.

Comment: Check a Kai Chan suggestion in this discussion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556870/what-is-the-biggest-size-number-of-documents-of-index-java-lucene-3-0-2-on-32 .

Answer (score 0):

On 32 bit Ubuntu, a JVM process can ask for something like 2Gb of heap memory before it hits the hard limit imposed by the hardware.  You've burned up half of that by asking for 1Gbyte of permgen heap.  This seems *way* too much to me.  Try with ~1.8Gb of ordinary heap and 200Mb of permgen.

Comment: OK, so it must be something else.  My guess is that it must be something to do with the way you've configured Lucene.